# Error during installation of openssh-server in Vmware workstation

Tags: software-installation, vmware

While running `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`, i'm getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the error in your post!

Comment: You may check the error message: `Failed to fetch ...` means that the Ubuntu cannot get the file. Check how the virtual machine is connected to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ubuntu in the VM unable to access internet. Fix the internet connection of the VM and your problem will be resolved.

Check the following troubleshoot guide for help.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1016466